# kivy did not make apk

Tags: kivy, apk

I am a beginner in Kivy for creating APK files. However, when I tried compiling with the "buildozer -v android debug" command in Google Colab, I encountered an error. The error message stated that the APK file was not generated in the bin folder.

```
# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
```

the above error
Buildozer failed to execute the last command

Buildozer failed to execute the last command